# Marketing Cloud Global Variable - use with AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I want to setup a global variable that could be used across the whole Marketing Cloud.
For example key/passphrase value for encryption functions. So if the key changes than I can change it just in one place.

Does Marketing Cloud supports something like this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider setting up a data extension with key-value pairs and then using ampscript function to do query on data extension to return desired value.

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to create a content area that sets a variable

```
%%[set @GlobalVar = "SOMEVALUE"]%%
```

Then reference this content area using ContentArea() or ContentAreaByName()

```
%%=ContentArea("7003887")=%%
```

Then you would be able to reference the variable set in the content area

```
%%=v(@GlobalVar)=%%
```